# Angular form clone does not submit data. But the parent form does

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, clone

I am working on an angular project whereby a table is cloned based on the number of debtors from the first form. So let's say the first form wanted 3 debtors included the next form will generate 3 forms. But when you try to save data from the cloned forms it does not work but the first form only works where the clone came from.

```
  **MY TS FILE**
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import * as $ from 'jquery';


@Component({
selector: "app-annex",
templateUrl: "./annex.component.html",
styleUrls: ["./annex.component.css"],
})
export class AnnexComponent implements OnInit {
annexform: FormGroup;
id: any;
data = [];
decreaseDebtor: number;
alert: boolean = false;
alertUnsuccesful: boolean = false;
// annexForm: boolean = true;
// debtors_included: number;
myDebtors: any;
debtorsCount = 0;
// submitted = false;
// myDebtorsSubmit : number;
constructor(
 public fb: FormBuilder,
 private http: HttpClient,
 private router: Router
) {
 this.annexform = this.fb.group({
   debtor_name: ["", Validators.required],
   debtor_contact_person: ["", Validators.required],
   debtor_function: ["", Validators.required],
   debtor_address: ["", Validators.required],
   debtor_email: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
   debtor_phone_number: ["", Validators.required],
   debtor_proposed_limit: ["", Validators.required],
   debtor_invoice_term: ["", Validators.required],
   debtor_projected_turnover: ["", Validators.required],
   debtor_ledger: [null, Validators.required],
   client: Number,
 });
}
uploadLedgerFile(event: { target: HTMLInputElement }) {
 const file = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
 this.annexform.patchValue({
   debtor_ledger: file,
 });
 this.annexform.get("debtor_ledger").updateValueAndValidity();
}

// convenience getter for easy access to form fields
get f() {
 return this.annexform.controls;
}

submitAnnexForm() {
 console.log(this.annexform.value)
 if (this.annexform.invalid) {
   return;
 }
 let formData: any = new FormData();
 formData.append("debtor_name", this.annexform.get("debtor_name").value);
 formData.append(
   "debtor_contact_person",
   this.annexform.get("debtor_contact_person").value
 );
 formData.append(
   "debtor_function",
   this.annexform.get("debtor_function").value
 );
 formData.append(
   "debtor_address",
   this.annexform.get("debtor_address").value
 );
 formData.append("debtor_email", this.annexform.get("debtor_email").value);
 formData.append(
   "debtor_phone_number",
   this.annexform.get("debtor_phone_number").value
 );
 formData.append("debtor_proposed_limit", this.annexform.get("debtor_proposed_limit").value);
 formData.append("debtor_invoice_term", this.annexform.get("debtor_invoice_term").value);
 formData.append("debtor_projected_turnover", this.annexform.get("debtor_projected_turnover").value);
 formData.append("debtor_ledger", this.annexform.get("debtor_ledger").value);
 formData.append("client", localStorage.getItem("id"));
 return this.http
   .post<{ id: string }>("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/annex/", formData)
   .subscribe(
     (result) => {
       console.log(result); 
ngOnInit() {
 let retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem("id");
 console.log(retrievedObject);
 this.http
   .get<any>(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/create-client/${retrievedObject}/`)
   .subscribe(
     (res) => {
       this.decreaseDebtor = res.debtors_included;
       localStorage.setItem("debtors_included", res.debtors_included);
       this.myDebtors = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("debtors_included"));
       this.debtorsCount = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("debtors_count"));
       console.log(this.decreaseDebtor);
       console.log(this.myDebtors);
     },
     (error) => console.log(error)
   );
 $(document).ready(function () {
   let debtors = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("debtors_included"));
   let e = $(".rowToClone");
   for (let i = 0; i <= debtors-2; i++) {
     e.clone().insertAfter(e)
   }
 $(document).find(".rowToClone").trigger("create")
 });
}
}
```

**THIS IS MY HTML FILE**

```
      <div id="myDiv">
        <form class="rowToClone table-form" name="annexForm" [formGroup]="annexform" (ngSubmit)="submitAnnexForm($event)" onsubmit="event.preventDefault()" >
          <table class="table">
            <!--Table body-->
            <tbody class="annex-body">
              <tr>
                <td class="table-input-data">
                  <input
                    class="my-input"
                    type="text"
                    formControlName="debtor_name"
                    required
                    id="debtor_name"
                  />
                </td>
                <td class="table-input-data">
                  <input
                    class="my-input"
                    type="text"
                    formControlName="debtor_contact_person"
                    required
                    id="debtor_contact_person"
                  />
                </td>
                <td class="table-input-data">
                  <input
                    class="my-input"
                    type="text"
                    class="table-head-data3"
                    formControlName="debtor_function"
                    required
                    id="debtor_function"
                  />
                </td>
                <td class="table-input-data">
                  <input
                    class="my-input"
                    type="text"
                    formControlName="debtor_address"
                    required
                    id="debtor_address"
                  />
                </td>
                <td class="table-input-data">
                  <input
                    class="my-input"
                    type="email"
                    formControlName="debtor_email"
                    required
                    id="debtor_email"
                  />
                </td>
                <td class="table-input-data">
                  <input
                    class="my-input"
                    type="text"
                    formControlName="debtor_phone_number"
                    required
                    id="debtor_phone_number"
                  />
                </td>
                <td class="table-input-data">
                  <input
                    class="my-input"
                    type="text"
                    formControlName="debtor_proposed_limit"
                    required
                    id="debtor_proposed_limit"
                  />
                </td>
                <td class="table-input-data">
                  <input
                    class="my-input"
                    type="text"
                    formControlName="debtor_invoice_term"
                    required
                    id="debtor_invoice_term"
                  />
                </td>
                <td class="table-input-data">
                  <input
                    class="my-input"
                    type="text"
                    formControlName="debtor_projected_turnover"
                    required
                    id="debtor_projected_turnover"
                  />
                </td>
                <td class="table-input-data">
                  <input
                    class="my-input"
                    id="debtor_ledger"
                    type="file"
                    (change)="uploadLedgerFile($event)"
                    required
                  />
                </td>
                <td class="table-input-data">
                  <button
                    class="my-input"
                    class="mybutton"
                    id="submit"
                    type="submit"
                  >
                    Save
                  </button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
            <!--Table body-->
          </table>
        </form>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a number of issues here.

- you have your ngInit callback method being called inside the subscription to the http request to POST data. that's either a copy and past error, or you really need to move that out of that subscription.
- As a general rule, angular doesn't advise Directly Manipulating the DOM as you have your code doing.

from what I can tell,

- you are manipulating the DOM in order to be able to have dynamic forms that respond to use events
- then you are trying to access these cloned elements in the class

the reason your cloned forms will never be available in the class is because you are manipulating the DOM directly instead of creating the objects in the class.

i.e. cloning the form DOM element will NOT make it available for use in the class.

you might benefit from going through the [dynamic form walkthrough](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form) on angular.io if you haven't already.

I would suggest either nesting FormGroups or using FormArray. using nestedFormGroups as an example you could do something along the lines of

```
constructor(
 public fb: FormBuilder,
 private http: HttpClient,
 private router: Router
) {
  this.annexForm = this.fb.group( {
     vendor1: this.fb.group(this.getVendorFormFields() ),
     vendor1: this.fb.group(this.getVendorFormFields() )
  });
}

getVendorFormFields() {
  return {
    debtor_name: ["", Validators.required],
    debtor_contact_person: ["", Validators.required],
    debtor_function: ["", Validators.required],
    debtor_address: ["", Validators.required],
    debtor_email: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
    debtor_phone_number: ["", Validators.required],
    debtor_proposed_limit: ["", Validators.required],
    debtor_invoice_term: ["", Validators.required],
    debtor_projected_turnover: ["", Validators.required],
    debtor_ledger: [null, Validators.required],
    client: Number,
  };
}
```

this allows you keep specific formGroups for each vendor, and allow you to isolate validation in the HTML template (if that is something you need).

an alternative approach, which might make things even easier to manage, would be to create a `VendorForm` Component. in this component, have the form and any validation you require. this would allow you to separate the logic that get/sets data from the form. this type of separation make managing your code much easier, and would allow you to more easily manage add/remove vendors and have the same form input controls for each.

on a separate note, you can save yourself some code by using `form.getRawValue()` on a form. this will effectively do the same thing you are doing with all your `.appendData` methods. it takes a form and returns a JSON object containing name/value pairs. you can then pass this into your HTTP request.

the short version I think here is that you are trying to do things to 'work around' angular to get at what you want. I would suggest following the dynamic forms examples provided by angular. there shouldn't be any reason to manipulate the DOM as you are currently doing.

Hope some of this helps. good luck